# Cut the output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

I have the following output of the command "xm list":

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0   505     4     r-----  11967.2
test1                                       28  1024     1     -b----    137.9
test2                                       33  1024     1     -b----      3.2
```

I execute a shellscript with: ./myscript test2
In this script, I need the ID of test2 (shown at the command "xm list" (ID33))
I tried it with grep and cut like this:

```
xm list | grep $1 | cut ???
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/xm

```
xm <subcommand> [args]
```

> **domid** *domain-name*
>
> Converts a domain name to a domain id using xend's
>   internal mapping.

Have you tried `xm domid test2` ?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that argument haha
Thats the easier way :D

Answer (score 5):

What about using awk?

```
xm list | awk '/^test2/ {print $2}'
```

I added `^` in `/^test/` so that it checks this text in the beginning of the line. Also `awk '$1=="test2" {print $2}'` would make it.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0   505     4     r-----  11967.2
test1                                       28  1024     1     -b----    137.9
test2                                       33  1024     1     -b----      3.2
$ awk '/^test2/ {print $2}' a
33
```

Answer (score 4):

With `cut` you cannot treat multiple consecutive delimiters as one, so `cut -d ' '` will not work.

Either use `awk` as in the other answer, or use `tr` to "squeeze" the spaces before using `cut`:

```
xm list | grep test2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Comment: I would add `^` to `test2` so that it is clear you are checking in the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not going to work:

Can be done just with grep:

```
xm list | grep -P -o '(?<=^([^ ]+ ){3}).*$'
```

Grep on my phone doesn't know -P flag, so I can't test it right now, but this should work.

## But this works perfectly:

Ok, previous code doesn't work, yes. Also I was trying to get the 4th column instead of 2nd.
But still, I insist that it can be done with `grep`!

```
xm list | grep -P -o '^test2\s+\K[^ ]+'
```

This code is tested and it works :)
The point here is that `\K` will reset previously matched text.

Comment: I does not work to me `grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Comment: @aleks-daniel-jakimenko how do you have `grep` on your phone?

Comment: @fedorqui yes, you're right. It was wrong to use lookaround assertions in this case, but I have edited my answer with another ``grep`` solution :)

Comment: @dogbane N900 runs Maemo OS. grep is installed by default as a part of busybox